# Data quality database model

Tags: database, database-design, metadata, data-quality

Need an example of a database model to be attached to a database for data quality. Best form of the answer would at the very least be DDL that's executable in MySQL; other RDMS DDL's are okay, I'll just post another question asking for a porting of the code.

A good explaintion would be a huge plus.

Questions, comments, feedback, etc. -- just comment, thanks!!

Comment: I don't understand any bit of that question. You need some DDL? Does it matter what it does?

Comment: @GolezTrol: Looking for someone that's created a meta-model that's attachable to databases to log the data quality attributes. Also, find it interesting you'd vote to close, but ask a question that would lead me to believe you don't even understand the question.

Comment: @blunders, is what you need something like an ORM tool?  Something that crates a database access layer automatically like the .NET Entity Framework? (http://www.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=0711051)

Comment: I'd have to second @GolezTrol's question.  Perhaps the question is answerable if you can spell out what you mean by "Data Quality?"  Do you mean something that can spot invalid data in a database?  Something that can prevent invalid data?  Any details at all would be a big help.

Comment: @Ken Downs: Being invalid is not so much a data quality, as in my mind just bad data - I'm looking to document the quality of data during it's life cycle in the database via data quality attributes. To answer the question, you'd likely have to have a solid understanding of data quality practices.

Comment: @gmagana: An ORM a method of modeling an OO code to a database, I'm looking for a data model to manage data quality.

Comment: @blunders: You probably need to start by defining "data quality". I think this is why you have us all confused about what you are asking. At first sight, "data quality" has absolutely nothing to do with DDL statements.

Comment: @gmagana: For example, most databases do not document the sources or methods used to collect the data as meta-data; which would in my mind be a requirement for such a meta-model. Any attempt to define data quality would have an effect on the readers view of my view of it -- I would like their view, and I'm also not looking for someone to make up an answer either. The request for a DDL is based on my request for a database model; the DDL is for me the way I'd like to receive the model.

Comment: @blunders, in a database we define quality as adhering to constraints and keys, the quality is in the database designers ability to create those.  Is there something there beyond a buzz-word, with all due respect?

Comment: @Ken Downs: Do you think the OP is aiming at recording the source of each value in each column? That could be one of several measures of quality. I can see how the source might affect a reader's interpretation. (Kind of like how SO rep affects a reader's interpretation.)

Comment: @Ken Downs: The quality of data may or may not have originated from the what data store it's currently in, or the way it was loaded.  As an example, if you have 10 copies of the "same" CSV file in one directory, the filenames where meaningless, the columns where the same, but the only difference was that the rows varied on average from file to file by 15% and the all had timestamps. If one row was in all the files, it'd have a higher quality rating than one that's just in the oldest. Some may see it as a way to define, measure, analyze, improve, and/or control the quality of data.

Comment: @blunders The example you give of the 15 CSV files sounds more like a statistical review of incoming data.  For the example given, methinks this is more about analyzing import streams than the database itself, and then loading such results to the database (or anywhere for that matter).  Perhaps a significant edit to your OP to give this and other examples would move things forward.

Comment: @Ken Downs: Maybe an edit is in order, though based on your reply it simply sounds like you've never take an approach to data quality and deployed it; which to me is what I'm interested in.

Comment: @Catcall: Just noticed your comment, and yes, you might say data quality is another name for the rep of the data. Nice comparison, thanks!

Comment: @blunders.  Perhaps you're right.  In all these years I've never thought about quality.  I'll have to look into that.  What should I google for that?  See you round, best of luck.

Comment: @Ken Downs: I've randomly looked at books over the years on the subject, look at one today that seems pretty "ok" - Practitioner's Guide to Data Quality Improvement. Google wise "data quality+(attributes,assessment,tools,report,management,analysis,measuring,assurance,etc)" -- thanks for commenting, since I know it's not the most clear cut question.

Comment: @Ken Downs: My own intro came from working as a programmer for a global manufacturer. I got a lot from http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/index.htm. For an introductory book, I used _Out of the Crisis_, by W. Edwards Deming. But I also studied _Juran's Quality Control Handbook_.

Comment: One other useful online source: http://www.statsoft.com/textbook/quality-control-charts/ I was the first person to apply quality control charts to database and accounting operations at the global manufacturing company I was working at. I'm sure somebody did it somewhere else before me, though. The ideas aren't new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem is identifying meaningful measures of quality. That's so highly application-dependent, I doubt that anybody will be able to help you very much. (At least not without a lot more information--perhaps more than you're allowed to give.)

But let's say your application records observations of birds by individuals. (I'm just throwing this together off the top of my head. Read it for the gist, and expect the details to crumble under scrutiny.) Under average field conditions,

- some species are hard for even a beginner to get wrong
- some species are hard for an expert to get right
- a specific individual's ability varies irregularly over time (good days, bad days)
- individuals usually become more skilled over time
- you might be highly skilled at identifying hawks, and totally suck at identifying gulls
- individuals are prone to suggestion (who they're with makes a difference in their reliability)

So, to take a shot at assessing the quality of an identification, you might try to record a lot of information besides the observation "3 red-tailed hawks at Cape May on 05-Feb-2011 at 4:30 pm". You might try to record

- weather
- lighting
- temperature (some birders suck in the cold)
- hours afield (some birders suck after 3 hours, or after 20 cold minutes)
- names of others present
- average difficulty of correctly
  identifying red-tailed hawks
- probability that this individual
  could correctly identify red-tails
  under these field conditions
- alcohol intake

Although this might be "meta" to field birders, to the database designer it's just data. And you'd design the tables just like you'd design them for any other application. (That's what I did, anyway.)

Comment: +1 While not the answer I was expecting, really like the example -- and it speaks to real world experience in the field of data quality; which is way more important to me than a concept that fits the question. Thanks for your comment above on additional resources on the subject. Again, thank you!!

Comment: The resources I cited are mainly about quality control in manufacturing. But you can interpret a business as a manufacturer of many products, and one of them is data--data of varying quality. I got that idea from Deming's book. Deming is the guy that enabled Japan's manufacturers to kick America's ass for the last half century. The Deming Prize (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deming_Prize) is named after him.